# base.html for Django Registration Redux

Tags: django, django-templates, django-registration

I am using django-registration-redux and everything works like a charm. However, I am a bit dissatisfied with the fact that it forces me to name the base template that it uses base.html, and that I have to put it in the templates directory.

I'd rather have it somewhere like this:

"/templates/registration/redux_base.html"

Is it possible to define this somewhere in my settings.py? I could not find that, but I think this must be possible. (Otherwise I am getting name clashes with other apps which is frustrating...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost all templates from redux are extending template "registration/registration_base.html", except of templates for activation (for some reason they are extending directly from "base.html"). Template "registration/registration_base.html" looks literally like this:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
```

So you can override that template (simply by creating "global" template for project on that location) and define here another {% extends %} or your whole new template.

But templates for email activation, as I mentioned above, are extending directly from "base.html" so if you are using them, you must overrite them separately.

Comment: I've made some [pull request](https://github.com/macropin/django-registration/pull/97) to change this, it's waiting for acceptance from package owner.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever it bothers you simply replace

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
```

with

```
{% extends "registration/redux_base.html" %}
```

And ofcourse create `redux_base.html` as you wish.